# ORA00920 error: invalid relational operator

Tags: oracle

When I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT.STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, REGISTRATION_DATE
FROM 
    STUDENT 
LEFT OUTER 
    JOIN ENROLLMENT ON STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = ENROLLMENT.STUDENT_ID
WHERE 
    NVL(ENROLLMENT.ENROLL_DATE, 0) = 0 
    AND STUDENT.REGISTRATION_DATE <= TO_DATE('02-15-2007', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

I get this error:

> ORA00920 error: invalid relational operator

Comment: I'm not sure why this error is popping

Comment: What is the data Type of column ENROLL_DATE?

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this line in the query and try

Replace NVL(ENROLLMENT.ENROLL_DATE, 0) = 0
to
NVL(ENROLLMENT.ENROLL_DATE, SYSDATE) = SYSDATE

Now the new query will be

```
SELECT STUDENT.STUDENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, REGISTRATION_DATE
FROM 
   STUDENT 
LEFT OUTER 
    JOIN ENROLLMENT ON STUDENT.STUDENT_ID = ENROLLMENT.STUDENT_ID
WHERE 
     NVL(ENROLLMENT.ENROLL_DATE, SYSDATE) = SYSDATE 
     AND STUDENT.REGISTRATION_DATE <= TO_DATE('02-15-2007', 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```